# How to write this T_SQL join without a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm stuck trying to write a JOIN that will produce a result set as per the Output example below but **without** the WHERE clause, which I included just to show what the correct data should look like.  If the WHERE clause is excluded, it gives the wrong results.

The #TblA table lists SQL Server instances on hypothetical site with the SQL Server Version and the build number, eg. '12.0.5579.0'

The #TblB table is a list of all (reduced for this example) SQL Server version and build numbers.

The aim is to get a result set that lists each SQL Server instance, SQLVersion and ProductVersion (Build) along with any ProductVersion (equates to Service Packs and Cumulative Updates) that is available in #TblB that is **higher** than the current ProductVersion for the given SQL Instance's Version and ProductVersion.

If you look at the example result set, it should repeat the #TblA rows relative to the higher ProductVersion rows in #TblB. This will allow for a Grouped report in Reporting Services, by the way.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tblA 

create table #tblA -- build info for specific servers
(
    SQLInstance varchar(128),
    SQLVersion varchar(32),
    ProductVersion varchar(32)
)
GO
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer1', 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4001.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer2', 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4001.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer3', 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.2000.8' )
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer4', 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5000.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer5', 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6020.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ( 'MyServer6', 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.5058.0' )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblB') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tblB 

create table #tblB -- ALL builds available
(
    SQLVersion varchar(32),
    ProductVersion varchar(32)
)

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3025.34' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3023.8' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3022.28' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3015.40' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3008.27' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2017', '14.0.3006.16' )

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.5026.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4474.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4466.4' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4457.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4451.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4446.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4435.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4422.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4411.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2016', '13.0.4001.0' )

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5579.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5571.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5557.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5556.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5553.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5546.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5540.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5538.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5522.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5511.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.5000.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.4522.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.4511.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2014', '12.0.2000.8' )

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.7001.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6607.3' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6598.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6594.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6579.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6567.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6544.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6540.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6537.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6523.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6518.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.6020.0' )
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ( 'SQL Server 2012', '11.0.5678.0' )
```

And the query is:

```
-- The following gives a correct dataset in the format required for grouped reporting but ONLY because of the WHERE clause
-- Want a neat query that will produce the same format for all versions without the WHERE clause 
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM
     #tblB b
     left join  #tblA a
     ON  b.ProductVersion > a.ProductVersion 
     AND a.SQLVersion = b.SQLVersion
WHERE
    a.SQLVersion = 'SQL Server 2014'
```

Output:-

```
**SQLInstance   SQLVersion  ProductVersion  SQLVersion  ProductVersion**
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5579.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5571.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5557.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5556.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5553.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5546.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5540.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5538.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5522.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5511.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.4522.0
MyServer3   SQL Server 2014 12.0.2000.8 SQL Server 2014 12.0.4511.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5579.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5571.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5557.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5556.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5553.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5546.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5540.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5538.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5522.0
MyServer4   SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0 SQL Server 2014 12.0.5511.0
```

Comment: Are you using a weird SKU of the product where you suddenly have to pay $millions more each time you use a `WHERE` clause? If not, why the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM #tblB b JOIN
      #tblA a
      ON b.ProductVersion > a.ProductVersion AND
         a.SQLVersion = b.SQLVersion
ORDER BY a.SQLVersion;
```

I can't figure out why you would want a `LEFT JOIN` in the final query.  Your version is effectively an `INNER JOIN` because of the `WHERE` clause.